# Token Edittext (Field) android

Tags: android, android-widget

Because some reason I need a Edittext like the red part in this image :

[image]

Whenever the user press delete button on keyboard, the edittext will delete one token instead of one word.
So, my question are :
Do we have an exist control like it?
or If not, do you know how can customize one.
Note : I don't need it the same 100%. Right now, I am thinking about using a TextWatcher or setKeyListener method for delete feature.

Thank you so much for any help. And sorry because my English is not really well.

Answer (score 4):

I've put together [TokenAutoComplete on github](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete) for our use at Splitwise. I couldn't find anything like this in the Android SDK, so I made my own.

The only place where the behavior of my control will not match your expectations is that when you delete the most-recently completed token, it turns into the word again. All other tokens get completely deleted.

Here's a basic example:

```
public class ContactsCompletionView extends TokenCompleteTextView {
    public ContactsCompletionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View getViewForObject(Object object) {
        Person p = (Person)object;

        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)l.inflate(R.layout.contact_token, (ViewGroup)ContactsCompletionView.this.getParent(), false);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(p.getEmail());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object defaultObject(String completionText) {
        //Stupid simple example of guessing if we have an email or not
        int index = completionText.indexOf('@');
        if (index == -1) {
            return new Person(completionText, completionText.replace(" ", "") + "@example.com");
        } else {
            return new Person(completionText.substring(0, index), completionText);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout code for contact_token (you can use any kind of layout here or could throw an ImageView in if you want images in the token)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/token_background"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Token backgound drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#ffafafaf" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Person object code

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Person(String n, String e) { name = n; email = e; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return name; }
}
```

Sample activity

```
public class TokenActivity extends Activity {
    ContactsCompletionView completionView;
    Person[] people;
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        people = new Person[]{
                new Person("Marshall Weir", "marshall@example.com"),
                new Person("Margaret Smith", "margaret@example.com"),
                new Person("Max Jordan", "max@example.com"),
                new Person("Meg Peterson", "meg@example.com"),
                new Person("Amanda Johnson", "amanda@example.com"),
                new Person("Terry Anderson", "terry@example.com")
        };

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, people);

        completionView = (ContactsCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        completionView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.tokenautocomplete.ContactsCompletionView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Android AOSP email client has something like you seem trying to do.
It is open source.

From [this commit](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/commit/87763f0ae851c76d5e7cf672a6e3acf21705549c) you see, that Google calls "chip" what you call "badge".

You should find all information regarding what it takes to implement such chips from the commit above, which I guess, was the first time Google introduced such chips (at least to mail), or in [the whole source of the AOSP email client](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/tree/master/src/com/android/email):

> Integrate chips into Email.
>
> Change-Id: Ice037a55a169037f725a667fad7714c7e9580b86

Comment: So sorry because I reply too late .
Thank you very much @cimnine. 
But it seem only available on ICS. I see it use RecipientEditTextView.  I can't see it on Android SDK. After research I found this one : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/+/refs/heads/master/chips. And I see it only available on ICS.(I haven't tried to implement follow your comment yet). My min Android version is 3.0.

Comment: Sorry that I can not provide a better answer. I searched for a solution some time ago and did not find something either. Allthough nothing stops you from back-porting the existing code to Android 3.0, I guess you go safer (and quicker) by thinking about a solution on your own. Why not make it opensource afterwards?

Comment: Hi. I think it is out of my ability. I am using another ways for my project. I did not using Edittext any more. And I think it like a hacky way. So. I should not public it. 
But I found this link : http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/customizing-the-android-edittext-behavior-with-spans/
I think it quite well, and maybe help other guys.